# Can I trigger/instrument an event from the command line and have it affect the Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications

I have an initializer in my config directory, which is something like this:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "handle_translation_event" do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
  puts "Called"
end
```

I have a Rails development server running ( `rails s` ), and I start in parallel a rails console ( `rails c` ). Imagine that in the rails console, I write:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("handle_translation_event")
```

I cannot see this reflected in the server logs. Is it possible to trigger an event from the console, and have it affect the server? My guess is no.

Comment: What do you mean "affect the server"?

Comment: To have the server handle the event ( it being sent from the console) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::Notifications` uses `ActiveSupport::Notifications::Fanout` class as notifier to notify the subscribers.

This notifier uses simple instance variables to store the subscribers.

You can create your own implementation (with a database backed solution) and you can set the actual notifier to your implementation by setting the `notifier` attribute of `ActiveSupport::Notifications`.

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.notifier = my_implementation
```

I could imagine a simple [Redis](http://redis.io/) backed implementation of it, because it has a [publish/subscribe](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) feature. But if you don't have Redis as a dependency, you can also do it in SQL.

Comment: But, as it is right now, it's not possible to affect the server from a console, right?

Comment: Unfortunately right, because the server and the console has it's own instance of `ActiveSupport::Notifications::Fanout`.